# using " in regular expression embedded in XML

Tags: regex, escaping, task

Currently I'm trying to replace the character sequence \" with " using sed in an ant task.
I successfully replaced the sequence \= with = but it just won't work for " because the parameter would end, no matter how much I escape the character.
This is the code I'm using for \=:

```
<exec command="sed" input="${inputfile}" output="${outputfile}">
     <arg value="-e"/>
     <arg value="s|\\=|=|g"/>
</exec>
```

How can I get this working? What is the right escape for a quote? Any help is very much appreciated! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using `&quot;` which is the entity for double-quotes in XML.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are writing XHTML. You don't escape `"` by writing `\"` in XHTML, but with `&quot;`. A full list of such "escapes" (they aren't escapes really, they are character entities) can be found here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp